# Ошибка: InvalidProgramException

Tags: pascal, pascalabc.net

Модуль:

```
///Предоставляет простые преобразования.
unit Transform;
{$gendoc true}

type
  ///Тип словаря, хранящего координаты точки.
  TPointDict = Dictionary<char, real>;
  ///Тип точки.
  TPoint = record
    X, Y: real;

    ///Вернуть строку, представляющую точку.
    function ToString()  := Format('Transform.TPoint: X = {0}, Y = {1}', X, Y);

    class function operator=(p1, p2: TPoint) := (p1.X = p2.X) and (p1.Y = p2.Y);
    class function operator=(p1: TPoint; i: real) := (p1.X = i) and (p1.Y = i);
    class function operator=(i: real; p1: TPoint) := (p1.X = i) and (p1.Y = i);

    class function operator explicit(p: TPoint): array of real;
    begin
      SetLength(Result, 2);
      Result[0] := p.X;Result[1] := p.Y;
    end;

    class function operator explicit(p: TPoint) := Dict(KV('X', p.X), KV('Y', p.X));
  end;

  ///Тип отступа.
  TMargin = record
    MarginLeftX, MarginDownY: integer;
    MarginRightX, MarginUpY: integer;

    ///Вернуть строку, представляющую отступ.
    function ToString()  := Format('Transform.TMargin: MarginLeftX = {0}, MarginDownY = {1}, MarginRightX = {2}, MarginUpY = {3}', MarginLeftX, MarginDownY, MarginRightX, MarginUpY);

    class function operator=(m1, m2: TMargin) := (m1.MarginLeftX = m2.MarginLeftX) and (m1.MarginDownY = m2.MarginDownY) and (m1.MarginRightX = m2.MarginRightX) and (m1.MarginUpY = m2.MarginUpY);
    class function operator=(m1: TMargin; i: integer) := (m1.MarginLeftX = i) and (m1.MarginDownY = i) and (m1.MarginRightX = i) and (m1.MarginUpY = i);
    class function operator=(i: integer; m1: TMargin) := (m1.MarginLeftX = i) and (m1.MarginDownY = i) and (m1.MarginRightX = i) and (m1.MarginUpY = i);
  end;

  ///Тип окна.
  TWindow = record
    Width, Height: integer;

    ///Вернуть строку, представляющую окно.
    function ToString()  := Format('Transform.TWindow: Width = {0}, Height = {1}', Width, Height);

    class function operator=(w1, w2: TWindow) := (w1.Width = w2.Width) and (w1.Height = w2.Height);
    class function operator=(w1: TWindow; i: integer) := (w1.Width = i) and (w1.Height = i);
    class function operator=(i: integer; w1: TWindow) := (w1.Width = i) and (w1.Height = i);

    class function operator explicit(w: TWindow): array of real;
    begin
      SetLength(Result, 2);
      Result[0] := w.Width;Result[1] := w.Height;
    end;

    class function operator explicit(w: TWindow) := Dict(KV('Width', w.Width), KV('Height', w.Height));
  end;

///Возвращает точку в оконных координатах.
function ToWindowCoordinates(p: TPoint; w: TWindow): TPoint;
begin
  Result.X := 0.5 * (p.X + 1) * w.Width;
  Result.Y := -0.5 * (p.Y - 1) * w.Height;
end;

///Возвращает точку в оконных координатах.
function ToWindowCoordinates(p: TPoint; m: TMargin; w: TWindow): TPoint;
begin
  Result.X := m.MarginLeftX + 0.5 * (p.X + 1) * (w.Width - m.MarginLeftX - m.MarginRightX);
  Result.Y := m.MarginDownY - 0.5 * (p.Y - 1) * (w.Height - m.MarginDownY - m.MarginUpY);
end;

///Возвращает точку в нормализированных координатах.
function ToNormalizedCoordinates(p: TPoint; w: TWindow): TPoint;
begin
  Result.X := 2 * p.X / w.Width - 1;
  Result.Y := -2 * p.Y / w.Height + 1;
end;

///Возвращает точку в нормализированных координатах.
function ToNormalizedCoordinates(p: TPoint; m: TMargin; w: TWindow): TPoint;
begin
  Result.X := 2 * (p.X - m.MarginLeftX) / (w.Width - m.MarginLeftX - m.MarginRightX) - 1;
  Result.Y := -2 * (p.Y - m.MarginDownY) / (w.Height - m.MarginDownY - m.MarginUpY) + 1;
end;
end.
```

Программа:

```
uses Crt, GraphABC, Transform;
var
  P: TPoint;

begin
  P.X := -1.25;
  P.Y := 0.25;
  Writeln(TPointDict(P));
end.
```

Почему вылетает с ошибкой **InvalidProgramException**?

Comment: потому что действие `TPointDict(P)` бессмысленное. Что Вы хотели здесь сделать?

Comment: Сделать преобразование точки в словарь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Точка не является словарем.

```
var
  P: TPoint;
  d: TPointDict;
begin
  P.X := -1.25;
  P.Y := 0.25;
  d := TPointDict.Create;
  d['X'] := P.X;
  d['Y'] := P.Y;
end.
```